# Google Maps (street view) embedded in a div, full screen broken

Tags: css, google-maps

I have a google maps streetview, which is working great:

```
<div class=\"street_view\" data-address = "30 Rockefeller Center" ></div>
```

I use the google maps API to geolocate and render a map (coffeescript)

```
# initialize google street view
  init_street_views = () ->
    $(".street_view").each ->
      address = $(@).data('address')
      div = @
      geocoder.geocode { address: address }, (results, status) ->
        if status == 'OK'
          ll = results[0].geometry.location
          svs.getPanorama {
            location: ll
            preference: 'nearest'
          }, (data, status) ->
            pos = data.location.latLng
            head = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(pos, ll)
            panorama = new (google.maps.StreetViewPanorama)(div,
            pano: data.location.pano
            pov:
              heading: head
              pitch: 0)
            return
        return
```

Everything works great:

[image: streetview_1]

However, when I click the full screen button, rather than taking up the full screen, it seems to just occupy one it's parent containers:

[image]

Is there something I need to do with css in the parent container to allow the street view widget to occupy the entire page?

Answer (score -1):

A class is supposed to be declared like this in CSS:

```
.street_view{
background: red;
}
```

Then you use it inside your div like this:

```
<div class="street_view">Your content</div>
```

So I suppose that your problem refers to your syntax inside the div. The whole fullscreen thing starts with JS but its style is declared inside your CSS class, so this could be your problem:

```
<div class=\"street_view\"
```

An other solution could be to inspect your JS code only if this code: `<div class=\"street_view\"` is provided to you be Google.

**EDIT :**

I have inspected the iframe that the map is included through this [Google's link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview)

Check the code here and make sure that your map is like this one:

```
<iframe width="425" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/streetview-embed" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```